# PHP - Fit Array of Numbers In 100%

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on poll results and I want to fit 4 dynamic numbers in 100%. Sorry if I didn't explain it correctly, I'm native Dutch and I'm having a hard time trying to explain it correctly.

This is what I mean: If my poll results are like this;

- Answer 1: 1 vote
- Answer 2: 1 vote
- Answer 3: 1 vote
- Answer 4: 1 vote

The result should be **25, 25, 25, 25**.

Is there a way to calculate this? I have all answer counts in a array like this:

```
$all_values = array($answers_1, $answer_2, $answer_3, $answer_4);
```

How can I accomplish this in PHP?

Comment: so basic maths?

Comment: basic maths - you are simply looking for the percentages - eg, `answer_vote_count / total_vote_count * 100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be easy enough. You can use [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) and [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with a [custom function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

```
$sum = array_sum($all_values);
$result = array_map(function ($value) use ($sum) {
  return $value * 100 / $sum;
}, $all_values);
```

You could cast the results before returning, but I don't know what type you want.

[Short Demo](https://3v4l.org/fJDri).

Comment: Based on array_map docs, present on your answer, argument 1 should be the callback, not the array.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I'll edit the answer right now.